# Counting a group of extensions (images) in a directory in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have folders with a mix of files and only want a count of the image type files.  The following is returning the total files in the directory, not just the images. What did I do wrong?

```
extensions = ['.jpg','.png','.gif']
DL_path = os.getcwd()
for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(DL_path):
    for original_file in files:
        todays_files = sum(1 for x in files if any(needle in original_file for needle in extensions))
        print(todays_files)
```

If I have one jpg, one png, and two txt files. todays_files should be returning a 2, but it is returning a 4.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) to avoid duplicated items:

```
>>> found_extensions = set()
>>> found_extensions.add('.png')
>>> found_extensions.add('.png')  # try to add .png again
>>> found_extensions
{'.png'}   # <-- appear only once
```

---

```
import os

extensions = {'.jpg','.png','.gif'}  # set literal

found_extensions = set()
for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    for f in files:
        found_extensions.add(os.path.splitext(f)[-1])
        # ^-- duplicated item is not added

print(extensions & found_extensions)  # to get itersection (&) => filter
print(len(extensions & found_extensions))
```

---

**UPDATE** To get the number of matched file counts for each directory:

```
import os

extensions = {'.jpg','.png','.gif'}  # set literal

for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    count = sum(os.path.splitext(f)[-1] in extensions for f in files)
    print(dirpath, count)
```

`os.path.splitext(f)[-1] in extensions` will check whether a file has the wanted extension, and returns `True` (= 1) / `False` (= 0). Summing them will give you want.

```
>>> True == 1
True
>>> False == 0
True
>>> sum([True, False, False, True, False])
2
```

Comment: When I do that in the 1 jpg, 1 gif, 2 txt in the directory, it does return a 2, but the next directory, with 1 jpg, 2 gifs, and 1 txt, it still returns a 2, when what I need is for it to return a 3.

Comment: @ScottC, I misunderstood your question. I updated the answer. Please check it out again.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Iterating over `original_file` is looping each character in the file name. Since non-empty strings evaluate to `True` the `any` function is always returning `True`. So you're counting each file.</s> I miss read the contents of the loop.

Instead you can get the extension for each file, then check if it's in your list of file types you care about.

```
import os
extensions = ['.jpg','.png','.gif']
DL_path = os.getcwd()
todays_files = []
for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(DL_path):
    for original_file in files:
        filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(original_file)
        if file_extension in extensions:
            todays_files.append(original_file)
    print(dirpath, len(todays_files))
```